# Is it possible to set an SMTP header in SMTPAppender?

Tags: log4j, email-headers, smtpappender

I've got an `SMTPAppender` configured and I'd like to have email messages sent by that appender to have the header `Auto-Submitted: auto-generated` added to the messages. (This allows auto-responders, for example, to stop sending out-of-office messages to auto-generated error messages).

I don't see anything in the log4j 1.2.x API to handle this kind of thing. Is it possible to do with the existing library? If not, is it possible with a little extra hacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if this capability isn't available with log4j (at least the 1.x line) out of the box.

I've created a class that will do this through configuration. It can be found on GitHub here:
[org/apache/log4j/extras/ExtendedSMTPAppender.java](https://github.com/ChristopherSchultz/log4j-1.x/blob/master/java/org/apache/log4j/extras/ExtendedSMTPAppender.java)